# Yii путь хранения кэша.

Tags: кэширование, yii

Имеется ли в Yii возможность менять путь хранения кэша в зависимости от ситуации? 
Допустим, для каждой группы пользователей, хранить кэш в отдельном каталоге
/cache/group_id/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какой в этом смысл?

Есть адрес на который сливается кэш, так пусть там все и лежит, зачем усложнять жизнь себе и окружающим?

**//upd**

```
Yii::app()->cache->set($key, $value);
```

Ну у тебя же кэш не лежит в одном значении $key?!

Есть допустим префикс для каждого юзера и каждого куска кода.

Допустим

uid1234_page123  для узера 1234 закешировали страницу 123, ну к примеру, а удалить тебе или почистить нужно кэш всех юзеров, ну так пробегить по всему кеешу и убери все где есть префикс **uid** не трогая другие префиксы. profit!

Что и где сложного?

+ ко всему в документации есть упоминание про использование тегов для кэше, что может пригодиться тебе и упростит задачу в сотни раз :) и не нужно пробегать по всему кэшу, достаточно кильнуть все с тегом USER или что-то подобное :)

пример из просторов инета и первой ссылки

```
// Добавление записи с тегами teg1 и tag2
Yii::app()->cache->set($key, $value, 0, new Tags('tag1', 'tag2'));

// Очистка кеша по тегу tag2
Yii::app()->cache->clear('tag2');
```

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос: разные данные кэшируются по - разному. То есть, где - то для каждого пользователя отдельно, а где - то для всей группы целиком. Так вот, допустим, необходимо очистить ВЕСЬ кэш для всех пользователей, которые входят ТОЛЬКО выбранной группы. Как это можно сделать? Если можно.

Comment: по каким ключам создается кэш:  
для каждого пользователя группы в отдельности: $group_id . "_" . user_id . "_" . date('d')  
для всех пользователей группы group_id + date('d')  
если это чем - то поможет

Comment: Спасибо за ТЭГи. )